# onCharacteristicChanged not called with BLE

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I've connected a blood pressure device and set notification in onServiceDicovered.

I set notify with every Characteristic. 
But onCharacteristicChanged is still not called.

```
public final static UUID CLIENT_UUID = UUID.fromString("00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");

gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, enabled);
for (BluetoothGattDescriptor dp : characteristic.getDescriptors()) {
    dp = characteristic.getDescriptor(CLIENT_UUID);
    if (dp != null) {
      if ((characteristic.getProperties() & BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_NOTIFY) != 0) { 
         descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
      } else if ((characteristic.getProperties() & BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_INDICATE) != 0) { 
         descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_INDICATION_VALUE);
      }

    gatt.writeDescriptor(dp);
    }
}


@Override
public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
    super.onCharacteristicChanged(gatt, characteristic);
```

I want to receive blood pressure, but onCharacteristicChanged never called.
But I can receive in ios or other sample code.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First, the property of `Blood Pressure Measurement` is `Indicate`, not `Notify`

https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/services/Pages/ServiceViewer.aspx?u=org.bluetooth.service.blood_pressure.xml

iOS the `CBPeripheral setNotifyValue` is automatic to set `Indicate` or  `Notify`, but android not implement.

Give you some code for reference

```
if (gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, true)) {
    BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = characteristic.getDescriptor(UUID.fromString("00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"));
    if (descriptor != null) {
        if ((characteristic.getProperties() & BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_NOTIFY) != 0) {
            descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
        } else if ((characteristic.getProperties() & BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_INDICATE) != 0) {
            descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_INDICATION_VALUE);
        } else {
            // The characteristic does not have NOTIFY or INDICATE property set;
        }

        if (gatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor)) {
            // Success
        } else {
            // Failed to set client characteristic notification;
        }
    } else {
        // Failed to set client characteristic notification;
    }
} else {
    // Failed to register notification;
}
```

Comment: I corrected my code about the property, but onCharacteristicChanged is still not called. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have used the other tool app(ex: nRF Master Control Panel) to test your device? is OK?

Comment: Yes, I've tested by nRF Master. My device is OK.

Comment: Un... maybe I forgot something. Sorry, can't help you to solve your problem.

Comment: I connected the device, and then, onServiceDiscovered is called. I setCharacteristicNotification in onServiceDiscovered.

Comment: That's OK. You corrected my property. Thank you very much.